# Foreground service notification can't show up, too many things

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a foreground service notification for my app, but for some phones, where they have too many things in the notification area it does not show up.
Is there some way I can increase the priority of my app, so it shows up first? Right now its like this, my app is not there[image]

Comment: Notification.Builder.setPriority()

Comment: and how should I know what priority to set, I mean, I don't know the priority of the other apps....

Comment: see Notification.PRIORITY_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try couple of things.
1. set the parameter "when" which is A timestamp related to this notification, to  notification object with a future time.

```
notification.when = System.currentTimeMills()*2;
```

2. issue notification with `PRIORITY_MAX` while posting the notification.

`notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;`

This PRIORITY_MAX ensures that the notification you are sending from your application is Highest priority, for your application's most important items that require the user's prompt attention or input.

But note that `priority` field that App can set is only indicates Relative priority for this notification.
Low-priority notifications may be hidden from the user in certain situations, while the user might be interrupted for a higher-priority notification.

And below line from Android docs makes things pretty clear.

> The system will make a determination about how to interpret this
>   priority when presenting the notification.

Comment: Best practice for that would be to use the `NotificationBuilder` instead of messing with those values directly. Use `NotificationBuilder#setPriority()`and `NotificationBuilder#setWhen()`.